# Kotlin's when with Pair - complicated contidions

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-when

I have complicated bussiness logic conditions which I want to resolve via when statement.
Let's say I have 3 enums Enum1, Enum2 and Enum3 and every has constans A,B,C,D... etc. And depending on value of Enum1 and Enum2 I need to determine list of Enum3 values. So I have function like this:

```
fun determineValues(enumPair: Pair<Enum1, Enum2>) : List<Enum3> {
   return when(enumPair){
       Enum1.A to Enum2.B -> listOf(Enum3.A, Enum3.B)
       Enum1.B to Enum2.C -> listOf(Enum3.A, Enum3.C)
       //..etc
    }
}
```

So far so good. However I have also condition when let's say for Enum1.C no matter what is in Enum2 I have to return some Enum3 values.
I was trying to add to when conditions like this: `Enum1.C to Any -> listOf(...)`, but it's not working. So I ended up with some ifs  before when and it makes my code really less readable (I have a lot of business conditions like this)

So my question is: what is the simplest and cleanest way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

This feature of doing pattern matching in `when` does not exist yet. Even what you are doing now is not really pattern matching - you're just creating some temporary `Pair` objects and comparing equality. See [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/destructuring-in-when/2391/25) for a discussion about this. For now, the most concise way to do this that I can think of is:

```
    return when{
        enumPair == Enum1.A to Enum2.B -> listOf(Enum3.A, Enum3.B)
        enumPair == Enum1.B to Enum2.C -> listOf(Enum3.A, Enum3.C)
        enumPair.first == Enum1.C -> ...
        else -> ...
    }
```